# Ajax call to angularJs call method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm still beginner to use this angular and want to dig for it's capability to get the return value from the controller.

I am just wondering if it's possible to use ajax call then get the return value to pass in the angular..

I create a function to get the value from my controller using ajax

```
function myData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/testGetMSSQL',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            return data
        },
        error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });        
}
```

So here is my aim, I need to pass the function above in my angular call like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.customers = myData(),
            $scope.people = [],
            $scope.currentPage = 1,
            $scope.numPerPage = 5,
            $scope.maxSize = 5;

        $scope.numPages = function () {
            return Math.ceil($scope.customers.length / $scope.numPerPage);
        };

        $scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function () {
            var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage)
                , end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;

            $scope.people = $scope.customers.slice(begin, end);
        });

    });
```

Right now it doesn't work but if I am going to pass a hard coded value it will work:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.customers = [{
            "Name": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
            "City": "Berlin",
            "Country": "Germany"
        }],
            $scope.people = [],
            $scope.currentPage = 1,
            $scope.numPerPage = 5,
            $scope.maxSize = 5;

        $scope.numPages = function () {
            return Math.ceil($scope.customers.length / $scope.numPerPage);
        };

        $scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function () {
            var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage)
                , end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;

            $scope.people = $scope.customers.slice(begin, end);
        });

    });
```

I am just refereing to this example:
https://codepen.io/jyothinagaraj/pen/ALoYgO

appreciate any suggestions/comments. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$http` rather than using `ajax` so that it stays in **angular digest cycle**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope,$http) {
     $scope.spinner = true;
     $scope.init = function(){

        $http.get('/Home/testGetMSSQL').then(function(res){
            $scope.customers = res;
            $scope.spinner = false;
        })
     }
     $scope.people = [],
      $scope.currentPage = 1,
      $scope.numPerPage = 5,
      $scope.maxSize = 5;

      $scope.numPages = function () {
            return Math.ceil($scope.customers.length / $scope.numPerPage);
      };

        $scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function () {
            var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage)
                , end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;

            $scope.people = $scope.customers.slice(begin, end);
        });

    });
```

and in `html`:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="init()" >
```

**Note:** Try to put some kind of spinner so that the UI is disabled till the `$scope.customer` is fetched from server side.

Comment: I tried but got error on braces beside init(). I already declared it as well on the html but got this error on my console.     "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"

Comment: @Rockn'Roll : Try now. I missed `$scope` before `init()`